# What’s this dishwasher part?

Tags: dishwasher

Opening my partially-full Maytag dishwasher I found a gunky plastic part sitting on the top rack. Examining the dishwasher I can’t figure out where it might possibly go. Any ideas?

[image: picture of bottom]

[image: picture of top]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://www.justanswer.com/appliance/cxg5j-found-rectangular-part-bottom-maytag.html), which says "This goes on the back of your upper wash arm. You may have to glue it back in place with super glue however" and shows [image: this picture].

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer! Please transcribe (or copy/paste) some of the relevant bits from that link to your answer here. As it stands, this is a link-only answer since there isn't much here to tell the next person what's up, and if that link dies (but... links _never_ die!) well, this doesn't help the next guy very much.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Updated the answer.